# Is there a way to interpolate a plain HTML element into a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

I'd like to use PixiJS and Next.js to create a screen-fitting optimal scale ratio stage. I'm aware of `@pixi/react`, but I want to create a game and it'd be inefficient to re-render the stage everytime an Isogenic entity spawns, unspawns, re-positions and rotates, considering there might be hundreds of entities.

I've tried running this:

```js
function createElement() {
  const element = document.createElement('span');
  element.innerText = 'span';
  return element;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <h1>Interpolated: {createElement()}</h1>
  );
}
```

Got:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLSpanElement]).

---

The PixiJS getting started page contains this code:

```
// The application will create a renderer using WebGL, if possible,
// with a fallback to a canvas render. It will also setup the ticker
// and the root stage PIXI.Container
const app = new Application();

// The application will create a canvas element for you that you
// can then insert into the DOM
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
```

So interpolating the HTML text would not work.

Comment: You might be successful using `return element.outerHTML;`

Comment: @Pointy I think there's no syntax for embedding raw HTML. Anyway, the PixiJS getting started's page shows `document.body.appendChild(app.view);`, so I suppose the `id` attribute is not used

Comment: Yea that's why I used the word "might" :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <h1>
      Interpolated:
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: createElement() }} />
    </h1>
  );
}

function createElement() {
  const element = document.createElement("span");
  element.innerText = "span";
  return element.outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to dangerously append a child to a component? (Because the outer HTML will simply lose the reference)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `useEffect` hook and a disjoint state at the moment to activate the level display in PixiJS.

```
// `Level` contributes the PixiJS canvas to <main>
const level = new Level();
const [currentScreen, setCurrentScreen] = useState<CurrentScreen>('sigIn');

useEffect(() => {
  if (currentScreen == 'level') {
    level.display();
  } else {
    level.destroy();
  }
}, [currentScreen]);
```